# My Homepage and Origin URL 28 days data is showing different, one is passed and another is fail

Tags: pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

In, Page speed Insight when I look up my Homepage [www.shine.com](http://www.shine.com) under desktop it shows passed however when I click on the Origin it shows failed.

I thought my Homepage and Origin is same but Pagespeed insight shows different.

Answer (score 0):

"Origin" refers to the entire website, which is all pages under `https://www.shine.com`.

The home page specifically refers to the page at `https://www.shine.com/`.

The PageSpeed Insights results are saying that desktop users experience good Core Web Vitals on your home page, but not on your website in general. LCP and FID are relatively stable across the site, but CLS is poor on other pages.

For example, the [search](https://www.shine.com/new/job-search) page has poor CLS:

[image: PSI results showing poor CLS]

I'd suggest going through your site analytics starting with the most popular pages and testing their URLs in PageSpeed Insights. When you find ones with poor CLS, you can use the Lighthouse audits further down the report to identify potential causes of layout shifts. Hope that helps!